# How to concatenate two tensors having different shape with TensorFlow?

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, neural-network

Hello I'm new with TensorFlow and I'd like to concatenate a 2D tensor to a 3D one. I don't know how to do it by exploiting TensorFlow functions.

```
tensor_3d = [[[1,2], [3,4]], [[5,6], [7,8]]]  # shape (2, 2, 2)
tensor_2d = [[10,11], [12,13]]                # shape (2, 2)

out: [[[1,2,10,11], [3,4,10,11]], [[5,6,12,13], [7,8,12,13]]]  # shape (2, 2, 4)
```

I would make it work by using loops and new numpy arrays, but in that way I wouldn't use TensorFlow transformations. Any suggestions on how to make this possible? I don't see how transformations like: `tf.expand_dims` or `tf.reshape` may help here...

Thanks for sharing your knowledge.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
import tensorflow as tf

a = tf.constant([[[1,2], [3,4]], [[5,6], [7,8]]]) 
b = tf.constant([[10,11], [12,13]])

c = tf.expand_dims(b, axis=1) # Add dimension
d = tf.tile(c, multiples=[1,2,1]) # Duplicate in this dimension
e = tf.concat([a,d], axis=-1) # Concatenate on innermost dimension

with tf.Session() as sess:
    print(e.eval())
```

Gives:

```
[[[ 1  2 10 11]
[ 3  4 10 11]]

[[ 5  6 12 13]
[ 7  8 12 13]]]
```

Answer (score 6):

There is actually a different trick, that is used from time to time in code bases such as OpenAI's baselines.

Suppose you have two tensors for your gaussian policy. `mu` and `std`. The standard deviation has the same shape as `mu` for batch size 1, but because you use the same parameterized standard deviation for all actions, when the batch size is larger than 1 the two would differ:

```
mu : Size<batch_size, feat_n>
std: Size<1, feat_n>
```

In this case a simple thing to do (as what the OpenAI baseline does) is to do:

```
params = tf.concat([mu, mu * 0 + std])
```

The zero multiplication casts the `std` into the same rank as `mu`.

Enjoy, and good luck training!

ps: `numpy` and `tensorflow`'s `concat` operator does not automagically apply broadcasting because according to the maintainers, when the shape of two tensors doesn't match, it is usually the result of a programming error. This is not a big deal in numpy because the computation are evaluated eagerly. But with tensorflow this means that you have to explicitly broadcast the lower rank (or the one that has shape [1, *_]) by hand using the `tf.shape` operator.